# How to update a table with the result of a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am a newbie and have recently become involved in a project to remove the serialization from one area of our business (so the materials in question become an undifferentiated bulk part rather than individually recognized items).

As part of this project I need to sum the quantity of units held by part and and then update a table with this value. Here is my first attempt:

```
UPDATE TABLE(AVT) a
SET a.qty = (Select part_no, sum(b.qty) from inventory_part_in_stock_tab b
where b.contract = '12505'
group by b.part_no
WHERE a.part_no = b.part_no);
```

I realise that this is totaly incorrect but will hopefully illustrate exactly what I am trying to do. I have managed to create a cursor based program that I think achieves what I want but is to slow to be practical.

This produces the right answer in list form on screen but does not update the file!

```
Select part_no, sum(qty) from inventory_part_in_stock_tab
where contract = '12505'
group by part_no
```

We are running Oracle 9i can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct code:

```
UPDATE TABLE AVT a
SET a.qty = (Select sum(b.qty)
               from inventory_part_in_stock_tab b
              where b.contract = '12505'
                AND b.part_no = a.part_no);
```

The mistake in your `UPDATE` query is that you are `SELECT`ing two columns - `part_no` and `sum(b.qty)` while you are updating just a single column - `a.qty`.

Also, there are two `WHERE` clauses in your `SELECT` subquery of `UPDATE` query. Looks like that really a `HAVING` clause after the `GROUP BY`. You don't have to do that.

Comment: Thanks very much I will go and try it out and get back to you

Comment: Thanks great answer that has solved my problem. One minor point I think the query should read: UPDATE AVT a SET a.qty = (Select sum(b.qty) from inventory_part_in_stock_tab b where b.contract = '12505' AND a.part = b.part_no); my fault originaly (no "TABLE")